# NodeJS API that will upload and update CSV file by calling multiple APIs for each row

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csv, backend

I have written a function to update the CSV file by calling multiple APIs for getting required information.

My question is can I make an API to upload CSV file and call this function to that CSV file.
I want to give the updated file as a response to the client. How can it be achieved or is there any other way?
Here is my main function:

```
async function processCSV(filePath) {
  try {
    const rows = []
    const uniqueReferenceNumbers = new Set()

    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
        const referenceNumber = row['Reference Number']
        console.log('reading from csv , referenceNumber:', referenceNumber)
        // Check if the reference number is unique before processing
        if (!uniqueReferenceNumbers.has(referenceNumber)) {
          uniqueReferenceNumbers.add(referenceNumber)
          rows.push(row)
        }
      })
      .on('end', async () => {
        if (rows.length === 0) {
          console.log('No unique reference numbers found in the CSV file.')
          return
        }

        // Assume that brand name is the same for all reference numbers in the CSV
        const brandName = rows[0]['Brand']

        // Make the first API call to get brand_uuid
        const brandApiResponse = await makeAPICallWithRetry(
          `https://api/v2/search/brand?q=${brandName}`
        )
        const brandUuid = brandApiResponse.data.data[0].uuid
        console.log('Brand uuid :', brandUuid)

        // Make the second, third, and fourth API calls for each unique reference number
        const updatedRows = [] // Accumulate modified rows in memory
        for (const row of rows) {
          const referenceNumber = row['Reference Number']

          try {
            // Make the second API call using the obtained brand_uuid and reference_number
            const secondApiResponse = await makeAPICallWithRetry(
              `https://api/v2/search/watch?q=${referenceNumber}&brand_uuid=${brandUuid}`
            )

            // Extract watch_uuid from the second API response
            const watchUuid = secondApiResponse.data.data[0].uuid
            console.log('watch uuid:', watchUuid)
            // Make the third API call to get product info
            const thirdApiResponse = await makeAPICallWithRetry(
              `https://api/v2/watch/info?uuid=${watchUuid}`
            )

            // Make the fourth API call to get product specs
            const fourthApiResponse = await makeAPICallWithRetry(
              `https://api/v2/watch/specs?uuid=${watchUuid}`
            )
            // Make the fifth API call to get price history
            const fifthApiResponse = await makeAPICallWithRetry(
              `https://api/v2/watch/price?uuid=${watchUuid}`
            )
            row['Product Info'] = thirdApiResponse
              ? JSON.stringify(thirdApiResponse.data, null, 2)
              : ''
            row['Product Specs'] = fourthApiResponse
              ? JSON.stringify(fourthApiResponse.data, null, 2)
              : ''
            row['Price History'] = fifthApiResponse
              ? JSON.stringify(fifthApiResponse.data, null, 2)
              : console.log(
                  `updating ${referenceNumber} with ${row['Product Info']}, ${row['Product Specs']} and ${row['Price History']} `
                )
            // Add the modified row to the accumulator
            updatedRows.push(row)
          } catch (error) {
            // Handle errors appropriately, e.g., log the error, skip the row, etc.
            console.error(
              `Error processing row for referenceNumber ${referenceNumber}: ${error.message}`
            )
            // Stop the entire process if the maximum number of retries is exceeded
            if (
              error.message.includes('Exceeded the maximum number of retries')
            ) {
              // Write accumulated data to the CSV before rethrowing the error
              if (updatedRows.length > 0) {
                const csvData = Papa.unparse(updatedRows, { header: true })
                fs.writeFileSync(filePath, csvData)
              }
              throw error
            }
          }
        }

        // Update the CSV file with the modified rows
        const csvData = Papa.unparse(rows, { header: true })
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, csvData)

        // Process is complete, you can do something with the results
        console.log('API calls complete, CSV file updated')
      })
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors appropriately
    console.error(`Error processing CSV: ${error.message}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is can I make an API to upload CSV file and call this function to that CSV file. I want to give the updated file as a response to the client. How can it be achieved or is there any other way?

For the API you can use Express.js and the Multer library for the file upload. Here's a [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/simplify-your-file-upload-process-in-express-js/) for a tutorial on how you can set it up, but to summarize, the API part would look something like this:

```
// Import libraries
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

// Initialise Express app
const app = express();
const port = 3000; // Port express will listen on

// Set up storage for uploaded files
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

// Create the multer instance
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    });

// Set up a route for file uploads
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    // Do the file processing here
    // Determine the file name and the absolute path
    let filename = req.file.filename;
    let filePath = path.resolve(`./uploads/${filename}`);
    // Process the file and send it as a response
    processCSV(filePath)
    res..sendFile(filePath);
    /*
    I'd suggest having the sendFile function inside a callback of the processCSV like so,
        processCSV(filePath, () => {
            res.status(200).sendFile(filePath);
        })
    Since the sendFile may get executed before processCSV due to the async nature of Node.js.
    */
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Express.js will listen on port 3000 and endpoint `/upload`. When a forum request with the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, with a file field, the file will be written with the naming format `CurrentDateInUnixEpoch-OriginalFileName`. Thus, a file uploaded with the name `example.csv` would be saved as `1700644354000-example.csv`. The absolute path for the file is found (i.e. the path relative to the root of the filesystem) and it is given to your function.

As I mentioned in the comment in the code you should have `res.sendFile(filePath)` in a callback to `processCSV()` since it may get executed before your function is finished.

Keep in mind this is just a starting point. You should do some more checks if you want to use this in production or anywhere outside a test environment. Test such as input size check, file format, check, etc. is essential. Remember, never trust user input.

For more information on multer here is its NPM [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).